# how to select one month back records from data base in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

how select one month back records from current date from database in laravel. I am trying this code.

This is controller code.

```
class LoginHistoryController extends Controller {

public function index()
{
$login_history = LoginHistory::where('login_date','BETWEEN', '(CURDATE() -  
INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND CURDATE()' )->get();
}
}
```

but i am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

I will have a approach something like this. First I will calculate the date like

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$date = date_create($today);
date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("30 days"));
$beforeOneMonth = date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
```

You should have the intended value in `$beforeOneMonth` by now. Now you can compare it in anyway you like whether you use `IN` operator or `>=`. For eg.

```
$login_history = LoginHistory::where('login_date','>=', $beforeOneMonth)->get();
```

Give it a try. If you are storing `date` in some other format, you can do your own tricks to format the date and do the thing

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be with `whereRaw`:

```
$login_history = LoginHistory::whereRaw(
    'login_date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND CURDATE()'
)->get();
```

Note that `whereRaw` has the side effect of making your code less portable since you're using SQL that might be specific to your database server. But sometimes you just can't do what you would like using the query builder.